# Build spatialite_i.lib error

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am trying to build QGIS from source on x64 Windows machine.

QGIS: qgis2.99.0
VS: 2015

I downloaded latest cygwin, OSGeo4W etc. Now, CMake gives an error:

```
Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W64/lib/spatialite_i.lib - not found
CMake Error at cmake/FindSpatiaLite.cmake:75 (MESSAGE):
  Found SpatiaLite, but version is too old.  Requires at least version 4.2.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:251 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

spatialite_i.lib ( I checked, rechecked and reinstalled couple of times ) is 4.3.0. If I remove spatialite check from cmake, I can create VS project, but then it gives errors on Link stage.

Comment: Perhaps not related but the author of SpatiaLite does not recommend cygwin https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/S2TgIufedTE

Comment: Yes, not related and I managed to compile finally( I posted solution below ). Still useful info, thank you. Will take it in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where configuring with CMake, I choose wrong option. Since everything is x64, in
"Specify the generator for this project" I needed to choose

"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" instead of just "Visual Studio 14 2015". Now all compiles fine.